# Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, массивы

Знаю что уже много раз отвечали на этот вопрос. Но я уже всё испробовал, но ничего не помогло. Ошибка указана в заголовке.

```
    $this->muted[strtolower($player->getName())] = 1;
    $sname = $sender->getName();
    $this->muted[strtolower($player->getName())]["muter"] = $sname;
    var_dump($this->muted);
    $this->muted[strtolower($player->getName())]["until"] = time() + 60 * $minuts;
    $this->restrict[strtolower($sender->getName())]["mute"] = time() + 60 * 2;
    $this->muted[strtolower($player->getName())]["reason"] = $reason;
    $pname = $player->getName();
```

Ошибка на линии, где я записываю в значение `'muter'` ключ `$sname`.
$muted обозначал через `$muted = [];` $player - объект. Функция getName() возвращает строку (имя). `$sender` - тот же объект с теми же функциями.

Comment: У вас `$this->muted[strtolower($player->getName())]` возвращает скаляр

Comment: большое спасибо